# Handling base64 encoded images with json_encode and PHP

Tags: php, base64, json

My PHP class returns a small base64 encoded image, link this:

```
class Service
{

  function getLogo()
  {
    $image = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c
             QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwA";

    return 'data:image/png;base64,' . $image;
  }

}
```

Returning the image using `json_encode` will add `\n` after each line of `$image`:

```
$service = new Service();
$response = array('name' => $service->getName(), 'logo' => $service->getLogo());
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

How to handle it correctly?

Comment: did you try http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've mangled your base64 data by splitting it across two lines. it should be

```
function getLogo() {
    $image = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4cQAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwA";

    return 'data:image/png;base64,' . $image;
}
```

with no line breaks.

Comment: Bad data or looking ugly on screen... your choice. I'll go with a bit of ugliness, rather than having to strip what amounts to lipstick and mascara every time the code runs. If you really are stuck on the formatting, then do `$image = "xxx"; $image .= "yyy"; $image .= "zzz"` type operations so you build the data up in pieces with no embedded line breaks/whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given by Marc B. This is just a comment. If code formatting really is *that* important to you that you can't tolerate long lines (*why?*), you could always format the PHP thus:

```
class Service
{

  function getLogo()
  {
    $image  = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c';
    $image .= 'QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwA';

    return 'data:image/png;base64,' . $image;
  }

}
```