# How to encode images to be used in an JSON array?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I want to do the following:

1. Connect to Amazon S3 and get an image (.jpg) or sound (.m4a).
2. Then I want to put them in an array of objects.
3. Send them to an client

The file exsists in the S3 and can be reached with an browser.

Step one is already done with the following:

```
try{
    $result = $client->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $filename
    ));
} catch (Exception $e) { //ERROR
    echo($e->getMessage());// FOR THE ERROR
}
```

I use the $result['Body'] to get the image.

*Note: the server is an EC2 instance so the password is already done with an role from IAM*

Step two:

```
image_array=[image1,sound1,sound2,image2];

echo json_encode(image_array);
```

This step is giving me an empty array. I understand that it is empty because of the encoding. The images are binary data objects and will not work fine with the JSON. But what is the right way? Should I do something like

```
image_array=[json_encode(image1),etc.];
```

Or should I do something like this

```
image_array=[utf8_encode(image1),etc];
```

**Question: How am I supposed to give the image back in an JSON code so I won't break and is readable?**

*Note: I use this to give info back to the client something similar to this*

```
total_array=[ [image1,property1,property2],
              [image2,property1,property2],
              [image3,property1,property2],
];
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with JSON and PHP, but usually when you try to encode binary data you could use Base64 and transmit the data as a string

Comment: True, i read about the base64 (forgot to mention in the post), but is that the right way to parse it in an json array?

Comment: As said, I am not familliar with it or it's best practises
But possibly this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244265/handling-base64-encoded-images-with-json-encode-and-php

Answer (score 1):

I have used base64_encode to transfer image data before.

```
base64_encode($image);
```

Comment: And then you can simply add him to the json array?

Comment: You could use the `base64_encode()` function directly in your array.
i.e. `$array = [base64_encode($image), 'some_string', $property]`

Comment: Ok so this do not work, The JSON is totally unreable in any way when returning it this way!

Comment: Could you update your question or comment with what you have tried using `base64_encode`?.

Comment: Exactly as you said, `$array=[base64_encode($image),'some_string'];` It then returns an string who starts with `["`. Also if I give it to http://jsonlint.com/ it says that it is not an good JSON string

Comment: You would still need to encode the array `json_encode($array);` and output it.

Comment: Yes, did that too, the client part is giving the error on the " as an unexpected character

Comment: Have you tried using the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option as a second parameter on the `json_encode` function? Perhaps the JSON isn't strict enough for your client, that is, it only expects objects and not arrays.

Comment: OK, so first is was hitting on the second character in the string was bad now with the second paramater you said it is giving me the error on character 5 ;)

Comment: So, the client does not like the " before the base64 image starts, is there some sort of explanation for that?

Comment: Can you paste the JSON, feel free to trim the base64 string so it is smaller. I'd like to see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEES, You are not going to believe what was causing the error!!!! All I had to was add `settype( $image ,'string');` .For some really weird reason PHP was seeing the S3 image as an integer (or any digit type) and thus was complaining about the " because it was expecting an digit. Many thanks @jacquestvanzuydam !!

Comment: @user3892683 I am happy you found your solution!